# Is there a way to get information about what video is playing in the Videos app?

Tags: ios, video, notifications, itunes

I know Apple does not allow the access of movies purchased through iTunes for licensing reasons.  In other words, I can't play a movie in an app I develop that was purchased through iTunes.

What I want to know is does the Videos app from Apple send notifications about what video is currently being played?  Better yet, does it provide information about the real-time status of the movie?  To clarify, I want to receive this information in a separate app that I am developing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This probably isn't possible because when you leave the video app, the currently playing video pauses.